# Geometric interpretation of Lawvere-Tierney topology

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

A Lawvere-Tierney topology $j$ on a sheaf topos $\mathcal{G}$ yelds a closure operator $\text{Sub}(1) \to \text{Sub}(1)$. If the topos is localic $\mathcal{G} \cong \text{Sh}(L)$ this yields a closure operator on the lattice of open sets $$\Gamma: \mathcal{O}(L) \to \mathcal{O}(L).  $$

> From a topological point of view, what is this closure operator?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. The answer depends on $j$. For instance, if $j$ is the double negation closure operator, then $\Gamma$ will be the double negation operator as well. Thus the corresponding sublocale will be the smallest dense sublocale.

Comment: Have you read my self answer?

Comment: Yes, I have. However I can't quite reconcile it with a different fact I know: Lawvere–Tierney topologies on $\mathrm{Set}^{\mathcal{P}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}}$ correspond to sublocales of $X$ (with $X$ considered as a discrete locale). I don't see right now how these correspond to topologies on $X$. For instance, one of the many sublocales of $X$ is the empty sublocale, which doesn't contain any points. But no matter which topology we put on $X$, the resulting topological space will still have points (assuming that $X$ is inhabited in the first place).

Comment: To be more specific: Assuming the law of excluded middle, there are precisely two Lawvere–Tierney topologies on $\mathrm{Set}$ (the special case of $\mathrm{Set}^{\mathcal{P}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}}$ for $X = \{ \heartsuit \}$), giving rise to the trivial topos and to $\mathrm{Set}$ itself. However, there is only one topology on $\{ \heartsuit \}$.

Comment: And you are absolutely right. I am wrong, I will correct my answer soon. Thanks for you correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a correspondence between the class of topologies on X and the class of Lawvere-Tierney topology over the topos $\text{Set}^{\mathcal{P}(X)^{\text{op}}}$, $$\{\text{topologies on } X\} \leftrightarrow  \{\text{LT-topologies on } \text{Set}^{\mathcal{P}(X)^{\text{op}}}\}.  $$ Here LT topologies essentially correspond to the closure operator $j :\mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ associated to the comonad $\tau \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ for a topology $\tau$ on $X$.

> Thus, an LT topology can be seen as a specification of a subtopology on a topological space.